# Pausing MATLAB program for GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a code which does some calculations, and then calls a GUI. In the GUI I have some options for user to select from. Based on that selection, further calculations are done.

```
Function this = random(this)

    ... some calculations

    GUI   % calls GUI
    value = getappdata(0,'value')   % Gets value from GUI

    ... some calculations

end
```

The problem is when the code is run, it calls the GUI and goes ahead with the program, how do I make the program wait until the selection in GUI is made, or rather the GUI is closed?

Comment: [`waitfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitfor.html) blocks execution until the object is deleted/closed

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use either `waitfor(GUI)` or `uiwait(GUI)` depending on what happens when GUI is called. `waitfor` is if GUI is an objecthandle and `uiwait` is if GUI returns a figure handle.